# GPUimagemovie (iOS) quality settings?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm integrating the GPUimage library in my app, so far so good:

```
NSURL *sampleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myFile" withExtension:@"mp4"];
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];
movieFile.runBenchmark = NO;
movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
movieFile.shouldRepeat = YES;
```

However, it feels like the compression settings are a bit off. I'd like to ramp up the quality of the video, but i'm not really sure how i am supposed to do that.

Can anyone point me in the documentation of GPUimage or give me an example? sadly the gpuimage samples don't show how that is done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently the compression settings weren't to blame (in my case at least).

What i was doing was wrong, because in my rendering pipeline, since i was using HDR textures for non video components, i had implemented my own bilinear filtering shader as well as setting texture binding to GL_NEAREST. That of course made the rendering of the movie a bit off, with artifacts that LOOKED like a compression issue, while in fact it was my fault.

In short, i think that the compression settings in GPUimage aren't to blame at all.